# Ruby invalid multibyte char error (Sep 2019)

Tags: ruby

My script fails on this bad encoding, even I brought all files to UTF-8 but still some won't convert or just have wrong chars inside.

It fails actually on var assignment step.

Can I set some kind of error handling for this case like below so my loop will continue.  That `¿` causes all problem.

Need to run this script all the way without errors. Tried already `encoding` und `force_encoding` and shebang line. Is Ruby has any kind of error handling routing so I can handle that bad case and continue with the rest of script? How to get rid of this error **invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)**

```
line = '¿USE [Alpha]'
lineOK = ' USE [Alpha]  OK line'


>ruby ReadFile_Test.rb
ReadFile_Test.rb:15: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
```

Comment: Please read https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Encoding.html

Comment: Running your code does not show any error to me. Also, it is not clear to me what you want to archieve ...

Comment: Have you tried to force encoding to UTF-8 e.g. `line.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)`

Comment: Another option might be to convert to binary, then to ascii replacing invalid chars with something meaningful or with a space even `force_encoding('BINARY').encode('ASCII', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => ' ')

Comment: @Christian, how you manage run it OK) on what version, what the trick? I am on Windows.   Anybody else getting an error like me ?  Tx

Comment: This could be IBM437 char in UTF_8 encoding.

Comment: Tx all, I tried all variants with `.encoding` including jamesc's. didn't work

Comment: I have tested Ruby 2.6.3 on Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue by saving the file with ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Running your code with the file in this non UTF8-encoding the error popped up. My solution was to save the file as UTF-8.

I am using Sublime as text editor and there is the option 'file > save with encoding'. I have chosen 'UTF-8' and was able to run the script.

Using `puts line.encoding` showed me UTF-8 then and no error anymore.

I suggest to re-check the encoding of your saved script file again.

Comment: Thanks Christian, yes once I save my test file in UTF-8 it worked OK. I used ScITE, though it was not original problem, as this string came after read file, which has that char. I will check now how it work with File.read in script saved as UTF. Tx Much